# SQL query returning results based off values in an array PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I Have two tables,

```
Table1
id - BIGINT
otherKey - VARCHAR(45) <---Unique

Table2
table1ID - BIGINT
```

The table1ID field in table2 is the same value as the id field in Table1.

I have an array containing values corresponding to the field otherKey in Table2.

```
myArray = {'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}
```

I am trying to return all Table2 rows whose otherKey value exists in myArray. I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE otherKey = ANY(myArray))
```

But I know using '=' , means the subquery can't return multiple results.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Are you just looking for `WHERE table1id IN (...subquery...)`?

Comment: Wow yeah, I guess I am, if you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right, if you want the outer subquery to match multiple rows from the inner subquery then equals isn't up to the job.

Which is why they invented `IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE table1id IN (SELECT ...)
```